# iptables tee rewrite destination IP

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

- I have server A: memcache server 10.0.0.1:11211
- I have server B: memcache server 192.168.0.1:11211
- I have full access to server A. I have no access to server B

**I want to replicate traffic received on 10.0.0.1:11211 to 192.168.0.1:11211**

I have set a this rule:
`iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p TCP --dport 11211 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.0.1`

I can see server B receive the packet, **however the destination IP is still 10.0.0.1**

How can I modify the packet on server A so it goes to the network with 192.168.0.1 destination IP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering myself:
never succeeded with iptables. maybe it's impossible because of TCP connected state.

instead, got it working with https://github.com/RobinUS2/teecp